# Hide class name on member elements in code outline

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse CDT (Neon.3 Release 4.6.3), and I'm working on a C++ project which has very long class names. For instance, I have a class named:

```
BoardPortInterfaceKernalComponentImpl
```

which means that, in the code outline for `BoardPortInterfaceKernalComponentImpl.cpp`, the first few member functions are represented by:

```
BoardPortInterfaceKernalComponentImpl::BoardPortInterfaceKernalComponentImpl(const char* const name, const u_int8_t, const u_int32_t)
BoardPortInterfaceKernalComponentImpl::~BoardPortInterfaceKernalComponentImpl(void)
BoardPortInterfaceKernalComponentImpl::write_data(u_int8_t)
```

Just as we can see here, in Eclipse, everything is obnoxiously wide. I have to either expand the code outline to span half of my monitor, or constantly fight with a horizontal scroll bar, which makes the code outline view useless.

Is there any way to hide the class name in the outline view? Ideally, I would see this:

```
BoardPortInterfaceKernalComponentImpl(const char* const name, const u_int8_t, const u_int32_t)
~BoardPortInterfaceKernalComponentImpl(void)
write_data(u_int8_t)
```

which is far more manageable.

*Note*: Changing the class name to something shorter isn't an option.

Comment: Hmmmm. I suppose getting an array of 4 4K monitors is also off the table? See if navigating to Window->Preferences->C/C++->Appearance and checking "Group namespaces" and Group method definitions" does what you want.

Comment: @user4581301 That did exactly what I needed, thank you! If you submit this as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

How about C++11 template alias?

```
using BPIKCI = BoardPortInterfaceKernalComponentImpl;
```